# How do I write my own function to create a z-score in R

Tags: r, function

I am practicing writing my own functions. I tried to create for function for creating z-scores

```
age <- c(25, 30, 28, 40, 50)
bmi <- c(22, 24, 30, 26, 35)

test.data <- cbind.data.frame(age, bmi)

zscore <- function(x, mean_x, sd_x, zscore_x) { 

test.data <- test.data %>%
mutate(mean_x = mean(x, na.rm = T),
sd_x = sd(x, na.rm = T),
zscore_x = (x - mean_x) / sd_x)
}

zscore(x = bmi, 
mean_x = mean_bmi, 
sd_x = sd_bmi, 
zscore_x = zscore_bmi)
```

I was hope to create a new variable called zscore_bmi that is added to the test.data, but the new variable is not created. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Three comments:

1. Your function `zscore` has 4 arguments (`x`, `mean_x`, `sd_x`, and `zscore_x`) but you only use one of them (`x`).  My first recommendation is to only have that one argument, like so:

   ```
   zscore <- function(x) {...}
   ```
2. The next issue is what to put in the body of the function.  Here, we just need the simple z-score calculation:

   ```
   zscore <- function(x) {
       (x - mean(x, na.rm=T) ) / sd(x, na.rm=T)
   }
   ```
3. You should *not* put `test.data` in the body of the function because it is not an argument to the function.  It would be much better to just calculate and return the z-score of your argument.  You can then assign that z-score as a new column to `test.data` like so:

   ```
   test.data$zscore_myvar <- zscore(myvar)
   ```

Putting this all together, here's what you want:

```
zscore <- function(x) {
    (x - mean(x, na.rm=T) ) / sd(x, na.rm=T)
    }  

test.data$zscore_bmi <- zscore(bmi)
```

Note that the R function `scale` does the same thing and can be used to check your work:

```
scale(bmi)
## 1.0431010 -0.6567673  0.5022338 -0.2704336  1.4680681
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set name in `dplyr` if it's `version >= 1.0`, use `"{{...}}" :=`.

```
zscore <- function(x, mean_x, sd_x, zscore_x) { 
  
  test.data %>%
    dplyr::mutate("{{mean_x}}" := mean(x, na.rm = T),
                  "{{sd_x}}" := sd(x, na.rm = T),
                  "{{zscore_x}}" := (x - {{mean_x}}) / {{sd_x}})
  
  
}

zscore(x = bmi, 
       mean_x = mean_bmi, 
       sd_x = sd_bmi, 
       zscore_x = zscore_bmi)

  age bmi mean_bmi   sd_bmi zscore_bmi
1  25  22     27.4 5.176872 -1.0431010
2  30  24     27.4 5.176872 -0.6567673
3  28  30     27.4 5.176872  0.5022338
4  40  26     27.4 5.176872 -0.2704336
5  50  35     27.4 5.176872  1.4680681
```